# Using the calc function with fr units

Tags: css, css-grid, css-variables

I have a 3x3 css grid for which I want to have the respective two outer column and row sizes be calculated. The middle ones are `1fr`.

So far I have:

(see also [this codepen](https://codepen.io/jth42/pen/RwePzZJ))

```css
html {
  --zoom-scale: 1;  
}

body {
  --weight: calc(((var(--zoom-scale) - 1) / 2 * 1fr));
}

.grid {
  grid-template-columns: var(--weight) 1fr var(--weight);
  grid-template-rows: var(--weight) 1fr var(--weight);

  /* Expecting this for --weight = 1 */
  /* grid-template-columns: 0 1fr 0;
  grid-template-rows: 0 1fr 0; */

  /* And this for --weight = 3 */
  /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr; */
}
```

My Chrome never accepts any calculated value for the template properties though. What's the correct syntax here?

As you may have guessed, the overall problem I'm trying to solve here is to divide a given rectangular space into a grid in such a fashion that the middle cell can be scaled up by `--zoom-scale` and still be entirely contained in the grid container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform calculation with `fr` you can verify this by using `grid-template-columns: calc(1 * 1fr);` and you will get an invalid value.

You can switch to percentage where you go from `0` to `50%`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  --zoom-scale: 5;
  --weight: calc(((var(--zoom-scale) - 1) / 2 * 10%));
}

.grid {
  background: beige;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: var(--weight) 1fr var(--weight);
  grid-template-rows: var(--weight) 1fr var(--weight);
}

.grid > * {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    This is the grid content we are going to zoom, sporting a long text.
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use margin to perform the same task with less of code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  --zoom-scale: 5;
}

.grid {
  background: beige;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid > * {
  background: red;
  margin:
   calc(((var(--zoom-scale) - 1) / 2 * 10vh))
   calc(((var(--zoom-scale) - 1) / 2 * 10vw));
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    This is the grid content we are going to zoom, sporting a long text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see using margins first. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

The `fr` unit isn't a mathematical operator (+, -, ×, ÷), so it can't be used in the `calc()` function.

---

The `fr` unit is simply a representation of free space. It's not an actual unit of length.

> [**7.2.4. Flexible Lengths: the `fr` unit**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit)
>
> A flexible length or `<flex>` is a dimension with the `fr` unit, which
> represents a fraction of the leftover space in the grid container.

---

The `calc()` function is a calculation using mathematical operators.

> [**10.1. Basic Arithmetic:
> `calc()`**](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-values/#calc-func)
>
> The `calc()` function is a math function that allows basic arithmetic
> to be performed on numerical values, using addition (+), subtraction
> (-), multiplication (*), division (/), and parentheses.
>
> A `calc()` function contains a single calculation, which is a sequence
> of values interspersed with operators, and possibly grouped by
> parentheses.

A solution to the problem in the question has been provided in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989755/3597276).